# Correct way to pass a dictionary to the frontend using python

Tags: python, html, flask

I am using python 2,6 and I am trying to send a dictionary to the frontend.
I have a dictionary like this:

```
{"dict": {"1": 26, "0": 32, "3": 12, "2": 13, "4": 9}
```

This is how I am passing them to the front end:

```
data_load ={}
    c['dictio'] = {}
    dataload['dictio']['values'] = dict
    .....
```

And in the frond end:

```
<td colspan="2" class="{{ data['dictio']['values']}}">
                    <h4><b>Values</b></h4>
                    <h3>{{ data['dictio']['values']}}</h3>
                </td>
```

The result is the list of values.
How can I modify my code to get the values like this:

```
26
32
12
13
9
```

Comment: what template engine are you using ? if it handles for-loop you should go with this

Comment: why not send it as Json? it looks like a dict, and can easily be converted to a dict.

Comment: I am using Flask

Comment: @DanielHeidemann How cand I convert and send it ?

Comment: The dictionary is a very long json and using for I slice it like this:  for k,v  in datas.items():
        exec("%s=%s" % (k,v))

Comment: @RamonaDaniela You can import the json lib like so: import json. Then you can use json.dumps(myDict) to convert it to json. you can read more here https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following pattern, with a for-loop to generate a tag `h3` for each value (replace the name tag to handle another kind of section):

```
<td colspan="2">
    <h4><b>Values</b></h4>
    {% for value in data['dictio']['values'].itervalues() %}
        <h3>{{ value }}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
</td>
```

The method  `itervalues` is supported by the template engine to return a generator of the dictionary values used by the for-loop.

But don't use `dict` as variable name in your code.

Comment: Hello @PRMoureau. I've chande the variable name. Anyway the for dousen't work. It just prints {% for value in data['dictio']['values'].itervalues() %}{% endfor %}

Comment: are you using `render_template` in your view to send the data ? Maybe you should add the code of your view and the template in your question